# itextsharp: getting height of image

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

i need to add a data table right after an image on a PDF in vb.net

last_pos=jpg2.height
datatable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, xpos, last_pos, writer.DirectContent)
unfortunately this is the output:

i highlighted broccoli, buckwheat, butter, cabbage. these are all part of a data table that is supposed to go after the bottom SEVERE word because the entire thing that you see is one image called jpg2 
[alt text http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/3661/fullscreencapture121520.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/3661/fullscreencapture121520.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .ScalePercent to stretch the image (I suspect this based on some of your previous posts), the actual dimensions of the image object do not change after you have applied .ScalePercent to it.  To get the displayed height of the image, you will have to:

```
jpg2.Height * my_scalefactor
```